# I want to see all deleted posts in my voting history

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, voting, deleted-questions

You can see your own voting history from your profile, if you click your profile and under the Activity tab, votes. If you reach 10K reputation, you gain the [privilege to see deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Now in your voting history, you can see all your voting history - up, down, delete, close, etc.

However, questions or answers that you upvote or downvote, disappear from the history when they get deleted by someone else. Posts where you close- or delete-voted, are visible in the history though.

Can up- and downvoted posts also remain visible in your history, please?

Comment: I only remember seeing posts that I voted to close / delete. The ones I downvoted didn't appear there (I remember because I always find them from my browser's history).

Comment: I'm logging all my votes for this reason. So far I do it manually, but that's OK. I just vote less. I've been thinking about a user script to capture them, but it's still just on the todo list.