# Deleted question not visible in my "Votes/Closure" activity

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, activity-tab

If I vote-to-close a question, and that question is subsequently deleted, normally I will still be able to see the question in my list of "Closure" votes in my user's "Activity" section. However, today a question which was deleted after I voted to close did *not* show up in that section.

This appears to be the only deleted question missing. Other questions which were deleted after I voted-to-close are still visible in the activity tab. Of course, it's possible there are also additional questions that were deleted and not shown, besides the one I've specifically noticed. But at the very least, the problem is not extending to all deleted questions.

Note that the question itself is still present, i.e. visible to 10K-rep users who have the URL. It's not that the question itself was removed from the site, but rather than it's just not showing up in the part of my activities where such a question normally would be seen.

I'm not usually sifting through my activity report (*), so it's possible this happens more routinely than I'm aware of. But this is the very first time I've ever noticed anything like that. It looks like a bug to me. Hence this report.

(*) This came up because I noticed a user posting an exact duplicate of a question they'd posted earlier and which I'd voted to close. I wanted to post a comment and reference the earlier-posted-and-deleted question, and so went to look for it in the activity report. That's when I noticed it wasn't there, even though other deleted questions where (as expected).

I have not included the links to the questions here (the author of the question then deleted their second attempt to post the question, after it got closed), as typically this should be avoided so as to not attract undue attention to the person in question or their posts. But I recognize that having these links might be useful/required in order to investigate the bug, so if a moderator or community manager would like those details, please just let me know what the appropriate way to share them would be (e.g. flagging this question with those details, or providing them in some other back channel).

Comment: Do you see other questions which you've VTC'd with the pink-deleted background? (I do)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to see all deleted posts in my voting history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400755/i-want-to-see-all-deleted-posts-in-my-voting-history)

Comment: @yivi They sound pretty related, but that other question looks to be about upvote/downvote history. This is about closure history. I can see the same issue with upvote/downvote history (which might be how it's been for ages / by design), but not with closure history.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: yes, I am still seeing other deleted questions which I've VTC'ed. It's just this one question that's missing.

Comment: @yivi: this is not a duplicate of that question. That question specifically notes that close-voted questions **normally** remain visible even after deleted, and is requesting the same behavior be applied elsewhere. My question here is reporting an exception to the **normal** behavior of showing close-voted questions after they are deleted.

Comment: I guess DMCA takedown or similar deletion?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: no. The question still exists. I have the link in my browser history and I can navigate to it. It just isn't being shown in my user activity. I will update the question to make that clearer.